# how to request htm attachment from couchdb then served as html on browser?

Tags: coffeescript, express, couchdb

Using express with coffeescript. What I want to happen is, request will get test.htm from couchdb, then have that htm file rendered (is that the right term?) on the browser.

I have this on my app.coffee

```
app.get "/testreq", (req, res) ->
  gets = require("request")
  myurl = gets 'http://jims.iriscouch.com:5984/album/attachment_id/test.htm'
  res.send myurl
```

On my browser, when I go to "/testreq", I get these instead...

`{
  "readable": true,
  "writable": true,
  "__isRequestRequest": true,
  "_redirectsFollowed": 0,
  "maxRedirects": 10,
  "followRedirect": true,
  "followAllRedirects": false,
  "setHost": true,
  "port": "5984",
  "host": "jims.iriscouch.com",
  "path": "/album/1d22186ee496b5ada564a9888d003203/test.htm",
  "uri": {
    "protocol": "http:",
    "slashes": true,
    "host": "jims.iriscouch.com:5984",
    "port": "5984",
    "hostname": "jims.iriscouch.com",
    "href": "http://jims.iriscouch.com:5984/album/1d22186ee496b5ada564a9888d003203/test.htm",
    "pathname": "/album/1d22186ee496b5ada564a9888d003203/test.htm",
    "path": "/album/1d22186ee496b5ada564a9888d003203/test.htm"
  },
  ....`

Changing res.send myurl to `res.render myurl` gives me an error (500 Error: Failed to lookup view "[object Object]").

What should I do to get test.htm (from couchdb) is rendered as html on the browser?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

```
  myurl.pipe res
```

Thanks for stopping by!